# Choosing aggregate roots without breaking invariants at the same time

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I'm trying to apply DDD to a model. 
How can I cluster the entities into aggregates, without breaking the invariants I have?

I have 4 entities (simplified):

```
public class Plan {
    public bool Completed;
    public DateTime StartDate; 
    public DateTime EndDate;
    public IList<Objective> Objectives;
}

public class Objective {
    public bool Completed;
    public IList<Person> Persons;
    public int TargetMeetingCount;
}

public class Person {
    public string Name; 
    public IList<Meeting> Meetings;
}

public class Meeting {
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;
}
```

- A plan has 0..* objectives
- An Objective has 0..* Persons
- A Person has 0..* Meetings

Invariants:

- A plan is completed if all objectives in the plan are completed.
- An objective is completed if the TargetMeetingCount is greater or
  equal to the Number of meetings for each person.
- Each meeting must be within the same date range as the Start and
  End date of the plan.

This is the way I'm reasoning about the solution so far:

If the Plan is an Aggregate Root with all Objectives, the problem is that as there are too many Persons and Meetings.
We don't want these many objects in the Plan aggregate. Calculating and retrieving data with the PlanRepository could be very slow.
Also if you want to show a list of plans, you don't want to retrieve this data.

So then the options is that we could make the Objective an AR as well and detaching the objectives, that would simplify the code a great deal.
An application service would assemble a "PlanViewModel" for the UI layter, by using a PlanRepository and an ObjectiveRepository and satisfy the invariants in the Plan.

However, if the Objectives are detached, we would break the invariant that a plan is completed if all objectives are completed, as the Domain Model itself can no longer verify this. So the 
"PlanViewModel" would be correct but not the Plan Model.

Worth mentioning here is that a Meeting object has many more properties in addition to the date range in reality, that we could filter by through the AR Plan, also that the Meeting object has no real purpose, as the actual completion status of an objective would be calcualated by a SQL query.

Not sure if I'm going the wrong way with all of this. But I have a feeling that eventual consistency could be used here, but I'm not really sure how that would apply that.
But maybe I'm only a completely wrong track here, I'm new to DDD and I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What happens after the `Plan` is completed? What additional invariants are in effect then?

Comment: As far as I know there are no additional invariants in effect. When a Plan is completed.

Comment: Then you can use eventual consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design you've chosen for your aggregates is something I see a lot of - too focused on `has a` relationships and the convenience of a nice object graph gained through composition.

> If the Plan is an Aggregate Root with all Objectives, the problem is that as there are too many Persons and Meetings.

You are correct. This is also a disaster for concurrency. You could get a lot of failing transactions because someone modified the `Plan` while someone else modified a `Person`.

Keeping your aggregates small leads to better concurrency, speed and scalability among other things.

I would probably treat `Plan` and `Objective` as aggregate roots. You might be wondering how do you keep the invariant between them consistent? Well you have to make a choice between **transactional consistency** or **eventual consistency**. In this case you'd be using eventual consistency.

When an `Objective` is marked as `completed` a domain event `ObjectiveCompleted` could be raised. At the application layer you have a service listening for the event. The event listener can:

### Use the `PlanRepository` to find out if it's complete

```
public function onObjectiveCompleted(ObjectiveCompleted $event)
{
    $planId = $event->getPlanId();
    $plan = $this->planRepository->find($planId);
    $isComplete = $this->planRepository->isComplete($planId)

    // Is the stored completed value consistent
    // with the newly computed value from the database?
    if (!$plan->isCompleted() && $isCompleted) {
        // They are not consistent
        $plan->markCompleted();
    }
}
```

The `PlanRepository` has access to the data store so it can do a query to determine if the `Plan` is complete.

### Load all `Objective` aggregate roots for the plan

```
public function onObjectiveCompleted(ObjectiveCompleted $event)
{
    $planId = $event->getPlanId();

    $plan = $this->planRepository->find($planId);
    $objectives = $this->objectiveRepository->findByPlan($planId);

    $plan->determineIfCompleted($objectives);
}
```

In the `determineIfCompleted()` method you would simply loop through all the objectives checking if they are completed. If they are then you'd update the `completed` field of the `Plan` to `true`. This is very easy code to unit test too which is great.

You would try to name the method as close as possible to your ubiquitous language. When you and your team talk about a `Plan` being `completed` maybe you call it "updating the status". In that case call the method `updateStatus()`.

### Conclusion

The first approach pushes the logic for determining if a `Plan` is complete into the data store. This may or may not be what you want.

The second approach keeps the logic right in the domain which I like but it could be less efficient when a `Plan` has 1000s of `Objective`s.

Also, do not concern yourself with view/presentation related concepts when working on the domain model. The domain model is for solving the business problem. Domain model and view model are separate. In certain cases you might use repositories from the domain to get data for the view (for convenience) but quite often you will just do directly to the data store. This is more efficient and gives you greater flexibility as you can do very complex queries that return data which is specifically for a given view (web page/HTTP API/desktop app etc).

I'm not going to design all your aggregates for you as I'd be here all night and don't know enough about your domain to do so. Proper aggregate design can be one of the toughest parts of DDD. Take your time and do it right. It will pay off in the long run.

Comment: Love to see `DDD`, `domain events` and `PHP` in one place but you should have waited to get all the details from the OP. How do you know that eventual consistency is acceptable in this case?

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! The second option sounds best as there are usually less than 20 objectives in total. Regarding broken invariants, does this mean that the model is really never broken as it can't check itself, i.e. the inconsistency is always temporary in the database until the event his fired and updated the completion status?

Comment: @AdEpt Some may think of it as broken and others may not. The main point is that all invariants will **eventually** become consistent. You need to ask your domain expert if he/she is okay with a very small delay. The model will only be inconsistent for the length of time it takes your domain event listener to be called and for it to perform its update (milliseconds). When you need to modify multiple aggregates during one client request then use eventual consistency. It is the small price to pay for keeping your aggregates small and simple which has many more benefits.

Comment: @AdEpt Vaughn Vernon has a three part guide on [Effective Aggregate Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838). I highly recommend you take a look at it. He actually covers the problems you are dealing with in it. I have read over it 5+ times and each time I took away something valuable I missed the previous times I read it.

Comment: @daviomey great, looks exactly like what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think an important thing to consider is what makes something unique.

For example can a person be involved in  more than 1 plan/objective?
Can an objective be part of more then 1 plan?

If a person can be involved in more than 1 objective then it becomes it's own aggregate root. (and objective would contain a list of personId's)

Also the fact that entities are part of an aggregate doesn't mean you have to actively load them into memory all the time. You could apply a lazy loading mechanism so you only load 1 person at a time and only when needed. The purpose of an aggregate root is to ensure consistency and be your entry point. It doesn't mean having all sub-objects in an array datatype and use a certain language. Those are implementation details and you have to wonder which questions (functions/services) to implement.
For example you  might have the function

```
AddMeeting (Objective o, Person p, Meeting m)
```

which adds a meeting to a person for a certain objective But would you ever have a

```
IList<Person> GetALlPersons()
```

function on a plan? If not then you wouldn't have to load all persons. You might get away with just a GetPeopleWhoDidntCompleteTheirMeetingCount() thus reducing the number of people you would actually have to load.

Comment: A person can be involved in more than 1 objective, but objectives are unique to each Plan. So you are right, a Person is its own aggregate, and a list of person ids would be enough. However, GetAllPersonsByObjective would actually make sense, as you would like to know which people has completed their TargetMeetingCount